# How can we replace %20 with - operator sign from url?

Tags: jquery

code:

I have created an autocomplete suggestion box which is completely fine. Now, I have redirect my selected item from autocomplete to url and my url look like

```
mywebsite.com/search.php?aa=Admission%20support
```

here I want to replace %20 with - operator sign after that my url look like

```
mywebsite.com/search.php?aa=Admission-support
```

So, How can I do this ?please help me.

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#show" ).autocomplete({
            source: 'search-result.php',
            minLength:2,
            select: function(event, ui) 
            {
                x = ui.item.value;
                y = x.replace(/%20/g, "-");
                location.href = "search.php?aa="+y;
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Thank You

Comment: Why not solve that server side in your 'search-result.php' file?

Comment: you have solved it yourself. :/ do you asking on how to receive the `$_GET['aa']` in PHP with "-" replaced with " "?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%20` is not encoded from `-`. Javascript has a built-in function to decode:

```js
console.log(
  decodeURI("mywebsite.com/search.php?aa=Admission%20support")
);
```

Refer [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/TagS/ref_urlencode.asp) for more information.

Comment: I have done buddy take a look  <script>
   $(function() {
       $( "#show" ).autocomplete({
           source: 'search-result.php',
           minLength:2,
     select: function(event, ui) 
     {
      var x = ui.item.value;
      y = encodeURIComponent(x);
      z = y.replace(/%20/g, "-")
      location.href = "search.php?aa="+z;
      return false;
     }
       });
   });
  </script>

Comment: it gives me the result http://mywebsite.com/search.php?aa=Admission-support

Comment: Thank you mate for your help :)

Comment: Of course, because your are replacing `%20` with `-`